# Hide DropDown when clicked outside in Next Js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

just started to learn Next Js. I wanna hide dropdown when i clicked outside the button. Code works fine in create-react-app. But i tried to implement in nextjs, it doesnt working.

```
     const LanguageRef = useRef();
  const [languageDD, setLanguageDD] = useState(false);
  console.log(languageDD);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!languageDD) return;
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
      if (
        languageDD &&
        LanguageRef.current &&
        !LanguageRef.current.contains(e.target)
      ) {
        setLanguageDD(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", checkIfClickedOutside);
    return () => {
      // Cleanup the event listener
      document.removeEventListener("click", checkIfClickedOutside);
    };
  }, [languageDD]);
```

link tag

```
 <a onClick={() => setLanguageDD((prev) => !prev)}>Language </a>
```

Does useEffect work in Nextjs?

Working Solution:

```
const LanguageRef = useRef();
  const LanguageDDRef = useRef();
  const [languageDD, setLanguageDD] = useState(false);
  console.log(languageDD);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect")
    if (!languageDD) return;
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (e) => {
      if (
        languageDD &&
        LanguageRef.current &&
        !LanguageRef.current.contains(e.target)  &&
        LanguageDDRef.current &&
        !LanguageDDRef.current.contains(e.target)
      ) {
        setLanguageDD(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", checkIfClickedOutside);
    return () => {
      // Cleanup the event listener
      document.removeEventListener("click", checkIfClickedOutside);
    };
  }, [languageDD]);

  <a onClick={() => setLanguageDD((prev) => !prev) ref={LanguageDDRef}}>Language </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I reworked and also splitted the `clickOutside` function to a `Custom Hook`, because it can reuse at the other components. Like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
export const useClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (e) => {
      // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
      if (!ref?.current || ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
        return;
      }
      handler();
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', listener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener);
      document.addEventListener('touchstart', listener);
    };
  }, [handler, ref]);
};
```

---

Finally, you just need `import` and use `useClickOutside` hook, like this:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useClickOutside } from '../src/hooks';

export default function Home() {
  const LanguageDDRef = useRef();
  const [languageDD, setLanguageDD] = useState(true);
  useClickOutside(LanguageDDRef, () => setLanguageDD(false));

  const handleToggleButton = () => {
    setLanguageDD((prev) => !prev);
  };
  return (
    <button onClick={handleToggleButton} ref={LanguageDDRef}>
      {languageDD ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: This helped. There is a typo above, though...
In the `return` of the custom hook, the second document. should be an `removeEventListener`